# An odd red box appears in uploaded page - source?

Tags: html, css

I have worked on a site for a class assignment. Looks fine on my computer, but uploaded, there is a vertical red area about 210px wide on the left side of the body and I don't know the source. (Both computer and uploaded are using FF.) I'm don't see anything in the code that is either that width or that color (#e62f2f). Could that have something to do with an error related to a form? I'm stumped.

Here is the posted site: http://bengal.missouri.edu/~gksc87/7370/satterfieldminiproject4plain.html

Comment: check your background at your #wrapper. use background-color: #035f03; instead of background.

Answer (score 2):

Its because of your

```
div#wrapper {
    background: #035f03 url("images/bg_tile_210pxw.png") repeat-y scroll 0 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}
```

remove that image. and should be like this -

```
div#wrapper {
    background: #035f03;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Maddy! That did the trick. Not sure why that only happened when I uploaded it.